# Get all the nodes connected to a node in Apache Spark GraphX

Tags: scala, graph, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Suppose we have got the input in Apache GraphX as :

Vertex RDD:

```
val vertexArray = Array(
  (1L, "Alice"),
  (2L, "Bob"),
  (3L, "Charlie"),
  (4L, "David"),
  (5L, "Ed"),
  (6L, "Fran")
)
```

Edge RDD:

```
val edgeArray = Array(
  Edge(1L, 2L, 1),
  Edge(2L, 3L, 1),
  Edge(3L, 4L, 1),
  Edge(5L, 6L, 1)
)
```

I need all the components connected to a node in Apache Spark GraphX

```
1,[1,2,3,4]
5,[5,6]
```

Comment: OK, so we understand what you need. What have you tried? Or are you expecting SO to write your code for you?

Comment: I do not expect the code but just basic outline for it.And for the question if it is required to write the stuff I have tried I think it will make the question a bit messy and not upto the point. Have seen the reference material for the Spark GraphX but was not able to get the solution for it.

Comment: Also there's `collectNeighbours` which seemingly does what you need: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#collecting-neighbors

Comment: collectNeighbors will give the information of node -> adjacent to that node list and collectNeighborsId will give just the ID of node so that wont help me for getting all the connected components

Comment: Output of collectNeighbors : 4 -> (3,Charlie),1 -> (2,Bob),6 -> (5,Ed),3 -> (2,Bob),(4,David),5 -> (6,Fran),2 -> (1,Alice),(3,Charlie)

Comment: You can achieve the goal manipulating by vertex and edge RDDS, the plan is the following: join vertex and edge RDD on vertex id, them map to other vertex id and finally group by key. As you are treating your graph as non-directional you may need additional manipulations, for example before joining you need to union your original edges with reversed edges (by the way you can do this and use `collectNeighbours`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`ConnectedComponents`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.ConnectedComponents$) which returns

> a graph with the vertex value containing the lowest vertex id in the connected component containing that vertex.

and reshape results

```
graph.connectedComponents.vertices.map(_.swap).groupByKey
```

Comment: If instead the graph was 6->5, 4->3->3->1, this would produce the wrong result, I think. It would still produce the same result and instead it should be (6, [5,6], 4, [1,2,3,4])?

Comment: These are not strongly connected components and choice of the label is arbitrary. Using lowest id makes sense so I don't think there is a problem here.

Comment: If the label is arbitary, yes, agreed. If the OP wanted the start of the subgraph, then there's an issue. But only the OP knows this.

Comment: Connected Components will find subgraphs, where each vertex has path to each other vertex. In fact it may be the whole initial graph if it is strongly connected.

Comment: you don't answer on his question

Comment: how to implement this in Java?